# Index.html Script Tag Values Replaced On Run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, amazon-s3, cors

## What are the details of your problem?

Why is the source changing before read by Chrome?

```bash
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://s3-example.amazonaws.com/aws-codestar-example/public/assets/head.html' from origin 'http://example2.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

[Web.Page.Value](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2695658?hl=en) seemed to change before [Page.Load](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp), but not so with the other pages.
And at time of original post, the homepage did not load properly with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) but all other pages with the same script loaded fine.
This didn't work on [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) but worked on `localhost` and on Firefox.

## What did you try and what were you expecting?

I tried changing [`S3 CORS`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors.html) configuration permissions but was unable to figure out how to fix this problem
[`AWS S3 Bucket > Permissions > CORS configuration`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enabling-cors-examples.html).
I'm still curious if anyone knows the answer, as I don't use jQuery much anymore nor non-same-origin deployments.
But, this has been an itch in the back of my mind as I've mostly worked around the issue rather than finding a moment to fully understand what's going on here.

##### Local

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script
            type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous">$(function () { $.get("assets/head.html", function (data) { $("head").prepend(data); }); });</script>
    </head> 

    <body class="container">
    </body>
</html>
```

##### AWS CodeStar

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script
            type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous">$(function () { $.get("https://s3-example.amazonaws.com/aws-codestar-example/public/assets/head.html", function (data) { $("head").prepend(data); }); });</script>
    </head> 
    <body class="container">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write the script in another page & link it in the bottom head or body tag.
As like:

```
<script src="Right the link page" type="text/javascript">
function...
</script>
</body>
```

Or:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Right the link page">
  function...
</script>
</head>
```

Write the script language in the *head* tag and try or in the bottom body tag.
As like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function...
</script>`
</body>
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>`
</head>
```

Than isn't than please remove your browser history, & close all tab than right the URL in the browser tab & run.